# Account import differs between eth and geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I created an account with `eth` and ended up with a JSON file in the [Web3 Storage Definition format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition).  After backing up this JSON file, I am able to delete my `.web3` directory and reimport this JSON file into `eth` as I would expect.

Now I'd like to try `geth` with my existing account.  As I understand, `geth account import` expects not the JSON file, but rather a file containing just the "ciphertext" value from the JSON file.  Upon providing that, geth asks me to set a new passphrase, then prints the address of the imported key.

Problem: the address `geth` shows for my imported key is different from the address `eth` knows!  And when I view the JSON file that `geth` created from my import, its "ciphertext" value is different from the one I provided.

Question: Starting with the JSON file I have, how do I import my account correctly into `geth`?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to import a JSON account file into geth is to copy the fule into the `keystore` folder.

- Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
- Mac: /Library/Ethereum/keystore
- Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum

If the folder does not exist, create it.

The reason that the `geth account import` command isn't working for you is that it expects the plaintext(decrypted) private key, not the ciphertext.